# Getting variable name inside a string in Python

Tags: python, string, variables, cursor

I have a variable db which is read from environment file. I am tryin gto use it inside a cursor execution statements as below.

```
config={}
with open('environment.yml','r') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f)
db = config['database_name']


result = cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE {db}.my_table")
result = cur.executemany('INSERT INTO {db}.my_table\
                             (id, description,code)\
                             VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                             list(tuple(row) for row in co.values))
```

I have tried using however not sure if this is the right way to include variable in string.

```
queryString = f'''TRUNCATE TABLE {env_db}.smartselect_qc_ordercodes'''
result = cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE {db}.my_table")
result = cur.executemany('INSERT INTO {db}.my_table\
                             (id, description,code)\
                             VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                             list(tuple(row) for row in co.values))
```

Comment: Use an f-string: `f"TRUNCATE TABLE {db}.my_table"`

Comment: You can specify the default database name when you connect to the DB, so you shouldn't need to substitute it into every query.

Answer (score 0):

```py
st = "TRUNCATE TABLE {db}.my_table".format(db=db)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).